# Judo techniques with their origin in BJJ?

Tags: judo, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, technique, history

Are there any techniques developed independently in BJJ since it branched off from judo which have hence been incorporated into Judo to success?

E.g. a novel type of armlock/strangle/pin, a non-Kodokan throw etc

Comment: This is a question whose likely best answer is "maybe, but probably not", at least until there is a serious effort to research if there is any evidence of such. What makes formulating a decent answer to this question difficult is that you can easily find examples of techniques that many in the more insular areas of the BJJ community believe is unique to their discipline but have been and continue to be used in Judo Ne-Waza; which should not be surprising considering that BJJ is in fact a derivative of Judo.

Answer (score 1):

Some potential candidates:

| Group | Techniques |
| --- | --- |
| **Gi chokes** | [*suso-jime*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iD6nAAAACAAJ&dq=fighting+judo) ([Gerbi choke](https://www.patreon.com/posts/evolution-of-22292882)) [*suso-jime*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iD6nAAAACAAJ&dq=fighting+judo) (Brabo choke) [*morote-jime*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vsXLqkIc2dAC&q=%22morote+jime%22&dq=%22morote+jime%22) ([*ude-jime*](https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/3zvufk/is_there_a_baseball_choke_in_judo/), Baseball choke) Collar and arm choke |
| **Arm-triangles** | Peruvian necktie Anaconda Ungvári (d'Arce, Brabo, Japanese necktie) |
| **Armlocks** | Huizinga roll (Omoplata) Biceps slicer* |